# Create a trigger trg_update_sw_license_avlbl which updates the license available in the sw_software_catalog table

Tags: plsql

Create or replace procedure sp_sw_sale_validation(p_software_name in varchar,p_client_I'd in number,p_license_required in number, p_statys out number) as

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.